# Images don't render on Android 7.0 (API 24)

Tags: android, image, react-native, render

I'm having this problem where a can not found a solution yet.

Here's the thing: I have this application which i need to render some images. Is a streaming app, so a have to render playlists thumbnails, video thumbnails, playlists cover and etcetera.

I can perfectly render those images in some versions like 6.0(api 23), 7.1(api 25) and 8.0(api 26). But, in version 7.0(api 24), **and only in this version**, no image is rendered

The code was built in  this way:

- I receive a set of playlists to render and inside a map function and i send each set to a component called HorizontalSquareList

  ```
  <HorizontalSquareList
       key={item.id}
       data={item.playlists}
       horizontal
       showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
       navigation={this.props.navigation}
   />
  ```
- inside HorizontalSquareList, i have a function called renderImage

  ```
  imageStyle: {
      width: width * 0.27,
      height: 100,
      borderRadius: 2,
  },

  function renderImage(item) {
      if (item.thumbnail) {
          return (
              <AsyncImageAnimated
                   key={item.id}
                   style={imageStyle}
                   source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }}
                   resizeMode={'cover'}
                   placeholderColor={'#cfd8dc'}
                   imageKey={`squareImg${item._id}`}
              />
         );
         // else, render an default thumbnail stored in server
   }
  ```

One curious thing is that default thumbnails that is stored in server are rendered, but thoose from api aren't.

So that is the problem. Only on android 7.0 those images aren't rendered. In other versions, it's perfectly fine. It's a problem with the API? Code? Android API?

Thanks in advance guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone gets here in the future, i managed to solve the problem by replacing 'https' for 'http' in the images i was receiving. I don't know why this happen.